# Checking for a tie in Tic Tac Toe Program

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Right now I'm trying to make a method that will check if there is a tie in my tic tac toe game. I have this constructed right now, but after 2 moves my program spits out "It's a tie!" When it shouldn't be. Here is my checkTie(); method code.

```
static boolean checkTie() {
        if(((table[0][0] & table[0][1] & table[0][2] & table[1][0]) & table[1][1] & table[1][2] & table[2][0] & table[2][1] & table[2][2]) == ('X' | 'O'));
        return true;
}
```

I have every coordinate in the table there, so this in theory should work, even though it is poorly constructed I will admit. Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: Maybe you meant `&&` and `||`. Hard to tell with so little context.

Comment: Agreed, hard to say what's going on.  Can we see the data structure that holds the game state?

Comment: Your question is poorly posed. You should explain, what your algorithm should do. Bit-wise adding is just right, but not for what you had in mind. We cannot read your mind.

Comment: Could we help you? Then please accept one of the answers and maybe upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use & here, as it is the bit-wise and. It will add all the bits and the result is X or O and thus you get a tie.

Probably you want to check whether all field are occupied. I'd do it like that

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
  for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
  {
    if (table[i][j] == '') // or however you store an empty field
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
 }
 return true;
```

Comment: What can I use besides & to link them all?

Comment: You are not supposed to link them. If you want to write it the way you did it, you should have checked each table entry: `(table[0][0] == 'X' || table[0][0] == 'O') && (table[0][1] == 'X' || table[0][1] == 'O') && (...) && ...` But you do not want to write that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work because you are using the bitwise `&` operator. It is used to combine single bits based on different patterns, not for combining chars or anything like that. Also, you are not returning anything if there is no tie.

You could change your code to something like that:

```
if ((table[0][0] == 'X' || table[0][0] == 'O') && ... ) {
    return true;
}
```

However, this would be a lot of typing; there are solutions way easier, for example by using a loop.

```
for (int x = 0; x < table.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < table[x].length; y++) {
       if (table[x][y] == ' ') {
           return false;
        }
     }
}
return true;
```

That piece of code is looping over every single entry in the array, if one is still empty, it will return false.

Comment: The loop you use gives my program an Array out of Bounds exception on the line `for (int y = 0; y< table[y].length; y++) {`       What would be the cause of this?

Comment: I'm sorry, obviously this has to be x not y, because we want the length of the array in `table[x]`.

Comment: After one input into the Tic Tac Toe programit tells me I have a tie right away now. Any ideas on what would cause that?

Comment: It seems you are inverting the returned value. `return false;` mean there is no tie, the game is still going on, check the call to that method.

Comment: I declare checkTie() right before this code: `if (checkTie() == true) {
    displayTable();
    System.out.println("It's a tie!");
    gamesCounter++;
    clearTable();
    System.out.println("Another Game? Yes/No :");
    String answer = s.next();
    if (answer.equals("Yes")) {
     break;
    }
    if (answer.equals("No")) {
     continuePlaying = false;
     clearTable();
     System.out.println("Statistics:");
     System.out.println(p1 + p1Wins + "/" + gamesCounter);
     System.out.println(p2 + p2Wins + "/" + gamesCounter);
     break;
    }
   }`

Comment: Then an empty string is not what represents an empty field in your code. It will work better if you take my code only as an example, and write the code that will be used in the final version on your own. It will fit into your application 10 times better.